# How to implement iterator for binary tree in breadth-first order

Tags: python

I have this binary tree but I don't know how to implement a iterator for this.
here is the code

```py
class node:
    """
    Defines a node in the binary tree
    """
    def __init__( self, value, left=None, right=None ):
        """
        """
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.value == other.value and self.right == other.right and self.left == other.left:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
       
class iterator:
    """
    Iterator for a binary_tree instance
    """
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.right = node.right
        self.left = node.left
        
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if 

        else:
            raise StopIteration

class binary_tree:
    """
    Implements a binary tree
    """
    def __init__( self ):
        """
        """
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.size
    
    def add( self, value ):
        """
        """
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = node(value)
        
        else:
            self._add(value, self.root)
    
    def _add(self, value, node):
        """
        """
        if value < node.value:
            if node.left is not None:
                self._add(value, node.left)
            else:
                node.left = node(value)
        
        else:
            if node.right is not None:
                self._add(value, node.right)
            else:
                node.right = node(value)
        

    def __iter__( self ):
        """
        """
        return iterator(self.root)
```

What I am trying to pass is:

```py
b = binary_tree()

for v in [4, 2, 4, 8, 1, 5]:
    #
    b.insert( v )

given = sorted( [v for v in b] )
correct_answer = [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 8]

assert given == correct_answer
```

I don't know or I'm lost how to implement breadth-first order and I don't want to use yield or any package or module.
What is the best way to implement a iterator for this type of binary tree?

Comment: Why _"I don't want to use yield"_? The simplest solution would be using `yield`.

Comment: Do you know how to write a breadth-first search? Do you know the iterator protocol?

Comment: I know yield is the way but the question is from the book and I am trying to find a way without it, its a rule in the book.

Comment: I know the idea of breadth-first search but I am lost how to implement it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator)

Comment: If you don't want or can't use `yield`, you need to implement a `__next__` method in the `iterator` class.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I updated the code how do I implement the `__next__` ?

Comment: By adding code that returns the next node in the tree given the current state of the traversal.