# TypeError: 'queue' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program in a queue class here is my code:

```
        def count(self): #im having a problem with this def count
            vowels=0
            for i in self:
              if(i=='a' or i=='e' or i=='i' or i=='o' or i=='u' or i=='A' or i=='E' or i=='I' or i=='O' or i=='U'):
                vowels=vowels+1
            print(vowels)
```

I'm having a problem with counting the vowels the user entered. It says "line 44, in  q.count()" and "line 16, in count
for i in self:
TypeError: 'queue' object is not iterable"

Comment: typo: `for i in self.items`

Answer (score 0):

Check how to create iterator : https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator

You have to implement `__iter__()` and `__next__()` which your class does not. That's why compiler tells you that `'queue' object is not iterable`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377/3780625) show you how to implement an iterator properly in Python.

Comment: w3schools is an awful resource, this question is pretty poor as well, they probably just have a typo `for i in self.items`

Comment: I updated my answer with the documentation from python.org and added a link for implementation example.

Answer (score 0):

"Iterator in Python is simply an object that can be iterated upon. An object which will return data, one element at a time.

Technically speaking, a Python iterator object must implement two special methods, **iter**() and **next**(), collectively called the iterator protocol."

According to the doc above, your `queue` object is not iterable, for it to be, you should implement the methods mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

If object of your class is supposed to be iterable implement what Maxouille's answer say, if this is not requirement you might elect to just replace

```
for i in self:
```

using

```
for i in self.items:
```

in method `count`