# Looping through an iterable data structure in python whose value changes every iteration

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, enumerate

My code looks like this :

```
input_list = [0,3,5,7,15]
def sample_fun(input_list):
    for idx,ele in enumerate(input_list):
        input_list = [x-2 for x in input_list if (x-2)>0]
        print('Index:',idx,'element:',ele,'New list:',input_list)
sample_fun(input_list)
```

What I am trying to show is that the value of input_list that is used inside of enumerate keeps changing inside the for loop. I want the for loop to iterate through the new value of input_list. But it appears that the for loop iterates through the initial value of input_list even though I am changing it's values.

```
Index: 0 element: 0 New list: [1, 3, 5, 13]
Index: 1 element: 3 New list: [1, 3, 11]
Index: 2 element: 5 New list: [1, 9]
Index: 3 element: 7 New list: [7]
Index: 4 element: 15 New list: [5]
```

I understand that the for loop is iterating through the initial enumerate output.
Is there any way I could make the for loop iterate through the new values of input_list like:

1. In the first iteration when `index: 0 and element:0, input_list = [1, 3, 8, 13]`
2. In the next iteration, I want the values to be like this - `index: 0 and element: 1 and input_list = [1, 3, 11]`
3. In the next iteration, I want the values to be like this - `index: 0 and element: 1`, now since the element is same as previous element value, I would like to loop through to - `index:1 and element : 3 and input_list =  [1, 9]`
   I want the loop to behave in this way.

I want to loop through the changing values of the input_list.
I'm not sure how to do this. It would be great if anybody could help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `for` loop, you keep assigning to `input_list` a new list object:

```
input_list = [x-2 for x in input_list if (x-2)>0]
```

while the iterator of the `for` loop is based on the original list object, and it therefore would not reflect the new list objects assigned to `input_list`.

You can instead alter `input_list` in-place by slicing its entire range:

```
input_list[:] = [x-2 for x in input_list if (x-2)>0]
```

so that the iterator can reflect changes made to the same list object.

Comment: When I tried the code, the index goes on increasing as the input_list values change. It is using the new values of the input_list, but I wanted the iteration to start from index:0 again as I have shown in the explanation of how I want the loop to iterate.

I know that this may not be possible using enumerate. But I'm looking for a way of doing this. It would be great if your solution could do this!

Comment: That's an extremely custom behavior you're describing then. You would certainly have to create your own class that implements Python's [iterator protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator) to produce the kind of iterable you're looking for. Please make your own attempt and, if you're stuck, post another question specific to the new code.