# Creating a non-iterator iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iterable

I was reading [What exactly are iterator, iterable, and iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration) and [Build a basic Python iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator) when I realized I don't understand in practice how an iterable class must be implemented.

Say that I have the following class:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        self.count = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count < self.num:
            v = self.count
            self.count += 1
            return v
        else:
            self.count = 0
            raise StopIteration
```

That class is **iterable** because it "has an `__iter__` method which returns an iterator"[*1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration). An object of `MyClass` are also iterators because "an iterator is an object with a `next` (Python 2) or `__next__` (Python 3) method. "[*1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration). So far so good.

What's confusing me is a comment that stated "iterators are only supposed to be iterated once"[*2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator). I don't understand why the following snippet gets stuck forever:

```py
>>> y = MyClass(5)
>>> print([[i for i in y] for i in y])
```

The fix, of course, is to not reset the `count` member:

```py
    def __next__(self):
        if self.count < self.num:
            v = self.count
            self.count += 1
            return v
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

But now the list comprehension has to create new objects in the inner loop:

```py
>>> y = MyClass(5)
>>> print([[i for i in MyClass(5)] for i in y])
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Now, let's say that I **want** to be able to call my object many times. I tried to implement an non-iterator iterable class with:

```py
class MyIterator():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        self.count = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.my_iterator()

    def my_iterator(self):
        while self.count < self.num:
            yield self.count
            self.count += 1
        self.count = 0
```

This works perfectly:

```py
>>> x = MyIterator(5)
>>> print(list(x))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(list(x))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But the nested comprehension gets stuck:

```py
>>> x = MyIterator(5)
>>> print([[i for i in x] for i in x])
```

And again the fix is to remove the line that resets the internal counter:

```py
    def my_iterator(self):
        while self.count < self.num:
            yield self.count
            self.count += 1
```

And change the comprehension to create new objects in the inner loop:

```py
>>> print([[i for i in MyIterator(5)] for i in x])
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

But the "fixed" class can't be iterated over more than once:

```py
>>> x = MyIterator(5)
>>> print(list(x))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(list(x))
[]
```

What's the correct way to implement an non-iterator iterable (note that I *think I followed the last comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377/6271889) to the letter)? Or is this use case explicitly not supported by Python?

Edit:

Classic case of [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), I changed the last class to:

```py
class MyIteratorFixed():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.my_iterator_fixed()

    def my_iterator_fixed(self):
        count = 0
        while count < self.num:
            yield count
            count += 1
```

What I had wrong is that I didn't need a `count` member because  Python already holds the state of the iterator method (in this particular case the value of `count`).

```py
>>> x = MyIteratorFixed(5)
>>> print(list(x))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(list(x))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print([[i for i in x] for i in x])
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

My question are now:

1. Is this the correct way to implement a non-iterator iterable?
2. When should I use a iterator and when should I use a non-iterator iterable? Just the distinction of one of them being called just once?
3. What are the drawbacks of a non-iterator iterable compared to an iterator?

Thanks!!

Comment: The problem is that `next` is not re-entrant: you are trying to use a single attribute `self.count` to track the state of multiple, independent iterators. Your final attempt is correct because the `generator` object returned by `my_iterator_fixed` correctly implements `__iter__` by returning itself.

Comment: "What are the drawbacks of a non-iterator iterable compared to an iterator?" The problem is you are thinking of these as separate things altogether, but in reality, the whole point is for *"non-iterator iterables* to *return an iterator which maintains its own state*. This is exactly the problem you are running in to. An iterator *encapsulates the state necessary to implement the logic of iterating*. Your iterable is using *internal state which ends up shared by all the iterators*

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, this is correct.
2. *Usually*, you want your iterator to be separate from the thing being iterated: it makes for a nice separation of concerns.
3. There are few, if any, drawbacks. Most iterable classes in Python do not act as their own iterators. File-like objects (which wrap file descriptors that already maintain their own file pointer) are the only exceptions that come to mind. For example,

   ```
   >>> type(iter([]))
   <class 'list_iterator'>
   >>> type(iter(()))
   <class 'tuple_iterator'>
   >>> type(iter({}))
   <class 'dict_keyiterator'>
   >>> type(iter(set()))
   <class 'set_iterator'>
   ```

   None of the four types considered implement `__iter__` by returning the object itself; they all return instances of a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a real life example of a non-iterator iterable might be helpful:
I usually work with language data and often implement some kind of container class for documents that holds the words, sentences, parts-of-speech tags, syntactic information etc., but the central structure is usually some list of tokens:

```py
class Document:
    def __init__(self, wordlist):
        self.tokens = wordlist

doc = Document(['Hello', 'World', '!'])
```

Whenever I need to iterate over the tokens, I could do `for w in doc.tokens`, but that's too cumbersome. So I would normally add `__iter__` that returns the stored tokens as iterator:

```py
class Document:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokens = ['Hello', 'World', '!']
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.words)
```

Now I can do `for w in doc:` which can be done unlimited times, and if the loop is broken in between, next time it will restart from the first word again, a behavior that seems quite natural to work with. But the object itself is not an iterator (because `next()` isn't implemented).

Answer (score 0):

My last iteration takes the hint from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690539/6271889)

```py
class MyIterator():
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __iter__(self):
        count = 0
        while count < self.num:
            yield count
            count += 1
```