# Is there a shorthand for tuple assignment in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tuples, assign

Wondering if there is a shorter version of the following in Python 3:

```
a = [(1,2), (2,3), (1,4)]
for e in a:
    n1, n2 = e
    ...
```

Access to all three variables `e, n1, n2` within the for-loop is required.

Thought of something like the following, but it isn't working.

```
for n1,n2=e in a:
    ...
```

The question has more of an academic character. I know it is not of a great importance.

Comment: Looks like you want the Walrus operator, `:=`.

Comment: @Mark: Sounds interesting, but seems not to work. Tried it with `for (n1,n2 := e) in a:` and even the other way around, but it throws a "cannot assign to named expression". Could you give a working example, please?

Comment: I wasn't actually 100% sure it would work, which is why I didn't leave an answer.  Sorry to mislead you.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely syntax would be

```
for (n1, n2) as e in a:
    ...
```

but, alas, no, this is not legal Python. You can still do

```
for (n1, n2), e in zip(a, a):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, the zip-way works fine, but I would guess that it adds a lot complexity for having some syntactic sugar. The `as`-syntax is PHP, right? ;-)

Comment: @Klumbe `as` is also used for [a very similar feature when pattern matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#capturing-matched-sub-patterns).

Answer (score 0):

for loop in python can unpack the iterated element.

so, the below code should give you the exact result:

```py
a = [(1,2), (2,3), (1,4)]
for i,j in a:
    print(i,j)
# out:
# 1 2
# 2 3
# 1 4
```

##### basic iterator(specific to this case)

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def __iter__(self):
        for tple in self.values:
            yield (*tple,tple)

case1 = Test([(1,2), (2,3), (1,4)])
for i,j,e in case1:
    print(i,j,e)
# out:
1 2 (1, 2)
2 3 (2, 3)
1 4 (1, 4)
```

Comment: You missed the most important part of my question: `e` must be accessible. I am aware of the unpacking, but I am wondering if I can unpack it while still being able to use the full tuple. Thanks for your answer anyways, but it did not really answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, I did not notice that `e` also should be accessible. You can create a custom iterator where it will return tuple and unpacked data too. something likes this : [basic iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/how-to-build-a-basic-iterator).

Comment: Thanks again, but this is even way more work to do then just adding a single line doing `n1, n2 = e`. Searching for something built-in to Python ;-) Not sure whether it exists, since I tried to find something, but until now, I did not have any success.