# how to set the gradient for a network in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient

I have a model in pytorch. The model can take any shape but lets assume this is the model

```
torch_model =  Sequential(
    Flatten(),
    Linear(28 * 28, 256),
    Dropout(.4),
    ReLU(),
    BatchNorm1d(256),
    ReLU(),
    Linear(256, 128),
    Dropout(.4),
    ReLU(),
    BatchNorm1d(128),
    ReLU(),
    Linear(128, 10),
    Softmax()
)
```

I am using SGD optimizer, I want to set the gradient for each of the layers so the SGD algorithm will move the parameters in the direction I want.

Lets say I want all the gradients for all the layers to be ones (`torch.ones_like(gradient_shape)`) how can I do this?
Thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyTorch, with a model defined as yours above, you can iterate over the layers like this:

```
for layer in list(torch_model.modules())[1:]:
  print(layer)
```

You have to add the `[1:]` since the first module returned is the sequential module itself. In any layer, you can access the weights with `layer.weight`. However, it is important to remember that some layers, like Flatten and Dropout, don't have weights. A way to check, and then add 1 to each weight would be:

```
for layer in list(torch_model.modules())[1:]:
  if hasattr(layer, 'weight'):
    with torch.no_grad():
      for i in range(layer.weight.shape[0]):
          layer.weight[i] = layer.weight[i] + 1
```

I tested the above on your model and it does add 1 to every weight. Worth noting that it won't work without `torch.no_grad()` as you don't want pytorch tracking the changes.

Comment: Is there a way to iterate over the grad of each layer? It seems that each layer put the parameters under a different name

Comment: I'm sure there is. Are you using tensorflow or PyTorch?

Comment: I am using Pytorch

Comment: If you are using `nn.Sequential`, you can get a list of all the modules in the sequence with `list(model.sequence_name.modules())`

If not, you can make your class iterable yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/how-to-build-a-basic-iterator

Comment: can you add a full code example in your answer? I dont see how do you reach and change the gradient (for example I cant find parameter sequence_name or how to find where the gradient suppose to be?)

Comment: I changed the answer. Should answer in full for you now.