# Is it possible to create a loop inside a child class?

Tags: python, for-loop, parent-child

I'm trying to see if it's possible to create a loop in a child class with `for loop`?

Anyway, here's what I made and trying to figure out how to achieve this (line 22-23) but unfortunately can't find a way. I'm new to python btw and exploring things

```
class Valkyrie:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.firstname = fname
        self.lastname = lname

    def printname(self):
        print(self.firstname, self.lastname)

class Character(Valkyrie):
        def __init__(self, fname, lname, age):
            super().__init__(fname, lname)
            self.edad = age         

        def intro(self):
            print(self.firstname, self.lastname, self.edad)

        def introd(self):
            print(self.firstname, self.lastname,",", self.edad)    
            

kk = Character("Kiana", "Kaslana", 16)
for x in kk:
    print(x) 

rm = Character("Mei", "Raiden", 18)
bz = Character("Bronya", "Zaychick", 14)
kk.intro()               
kk.introd()
rm.intro()
bz.intro()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a basic iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/how-to-build-a-basic-iterator)

Comment: What exactly you want to iterate over?

Comment: What is the expected output of the for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your example but summarizing, yes, you can create a loop inside a child class.

Let's consider this example:

```
class Parent_class:
    def __init_(self,name,last_name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        selg.age = age
    def print_name(self):
        print('The name is ',self.name,' ',self.last_name,'\n')


class Child_class(list(PARENT_CLASSES)):
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age):
        super().__init__(name, last_name, age)   
    def introduce(self):
        for person in PARENT_CLASSES:
            person.print_name()
```

If you pass a list of `PARENT_CLASSES` to the child class and, then, invoke its `introduce` function, it will give you the details of every person listed in `PARENT_CLASSES`